# dart:json in Dart programming language

Tags: dart

I have read in some books that dart has a library called **dart:json**. I have the 1.6 version of the Dart SDK and Dartium but I haven't been able to find any such library.

Comment: Where did you see a reference to dart:json?

Answer (score 5):

I think what you want is `dart:convert` wich includes everything you need to work with json. Have a look [here](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:convert).

Example:

```dart
var encoded = JSON.encode([1, 2, { "a": null }]);
var decoded = JSON.decode('["foo", { "bar": 499 }]');
```

`JSON.decode` gives you a `List` or `Map` depending on your JSON string and `JSON.encode` returns your JSON string.

Comment: Yup, `dart:json` was deprecated and eventually folded into `dart:convert`.